# Input shape for 1D CNN

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network

I have thousands image size of (750,750,3). I want to feed these images to 1D CNN. How can I convert this input shape to be utilized in 1D CNN? What should be the input shape? How can I do that before training process?

I have tried to reshape the size of the images but not sure how to do so as I am new to CNN.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for a `flatten` operation. Flattening reduces a `M x N x O` shaped array to a `M * N * O` 1-D array.

Consider this [example](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

So your (750, 750, 3) RGB image turns into a (1687500) array. Keep in mind that there are different options (channel first, etc.).